# JQuery Tile Editor

Tags: jquery, dictionary, editor, tile

I'm looking to build a simple tile editor to speed things up, rather than having to modify my long array map...

```
var mapArray = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
...
}
```

I know that I'll need to use JQuery UI for **Drag & Drop** functionality,
but I'm stuck on two main points:

**1.** How do I drag and drap only part of an image (or a tileset) to the map.
(in other words, I want to have all my of my images on one large image and just drag the parts that I need to the map).

**2.** I'd like like to have a Save button that would create a new tab (or add to Notepad) the *mapArray* data that I modified with the editor.

I've looked for plugins, none of them really do what I wanted them to, and I'd like to create this on my own and keep it simple, so If someone can provide helpful examples without the use of a plugin, I'd love that.

I hope that I've been straightforward.

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever tried to do something?

Comment: Yes but I don't know what to do about the two things I listed. I've never made a Tile Editor before.

Comment: When you have some code with problems that need fixing then let us know.  Stack Overflow is not for asking people to write your code :)

Comment: He's not asking anyone to write the code, he's just asking for a way to proceed.